# vim: delete to character, non-inclusive

Tags: vim

Suppose I'm in a certain line position in vim and I want to delete up to a certain character, say a semicolon. I would do `df;` except it would also delete the semicolon. Is there a command that will do the same thing but will not include the character I'm searching for?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Yes, `dt;`. From the [Vim docs](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#t):

> t{char}
>
> Till before [count]'th occurrence of {char} to the right.  The cursor is placed on the character left of {char} |inclusive|. {char} can be entered like with the |f| command.

Answer (score 23):

To add to what Michal said, you can also use `T` and `F` to do the same thing backwards.

Also `;` will repeat the last t,T,f or F motion, and `'` will repeat it in the opposite direction.

Comment: you meant `comma` to `apostrophe` right?